# Creating a loop that runs through each item

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

a loop if  purchaseid matches vendorid, If match set the sublistvalue of purchase cost else update with the new purchase cost, the loop should run through each an every item until the end

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just need a for loop, running on the line count (there's not a lot of detail to your question, so that's just a guess).

You need to know when you want it to run, and the internal IDs for each of the sublists/fields that you are touching/referencing.  Once you have that, you should be good.  The SuiteScript docs are a great place to start.  When logged into your NetSuite instance, click the Help link in the top right, and search for "SuiteScript 2.0 Modules".